# Server.MapPath isn't pointing to the actual server path when deployed

Tags: asp.net

I put the server.MapPath code in ASP.NET VB code behind.

On my laptop i compile and build. However when i upload my web application to the actual server. I received error where the link is still referencing the laptop link.

How can i solve this issue?

My code is

```
Server.MapPath("./scorecardsheet/db.xls")
```

Actual server link is `c:\Inetpub\vhosts\xxx.com\httpdocs\xxx\scorecardsheet\db.xls`

but when i run the page on the server it shows the link of my development platform as `c:\user\jerry\visual studio 2010\projects\xxx\xxx\scorecardsheet\db.xls`

Comment: You might want to show some code of that link: the fragment of the asp.net where that link is plus the code you use to set it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `Server.MapPath("~/scorecardsheet/db.xls")` instead, yes? Note the special ASP.NET tilde (`~`) symbol instead of the current directory symbol (`.`) This way it will calculate the relative path based on the location of the web site root wherever it is on the system.